# Scripting java : import a class from an external file

Tags: java, scripting, mozilla, rhino, java-6

I want to import a class that I already write in an external folder,
for example : 
My class `Example.java` that is located in `c:\class\Example.java` to my script like using

```
var importedClass = new JavaImporter("c:\\class\\Example.java");
```

or

```
importClass("c:\\class\\Example.java");
```

this is in a script for ScriptEngine rhino
how can I do that ???

Comment: Any reason you can't use the classpath?

Comment: Do you want to import a Java class in JavaScript that will be run using Rhino? Or do you want to import a JavaScript class in Java using Rhino?

Comment: I want to import a Java class in a JavaScript file that will be run using Rhino :)
this is it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I understand that you want to:

1. Compile a Java source file
2. Load the compiled code
3. Use the resultant class in some JavaScript

The [javax.tools](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/package-summary.html) package provides a mechanism for compiling code, though if you're not running in a JDK, [ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/ToolProvider.html#getSystemJavaCompiler()) will return `null` and you'll have to rely on some other compilation mechanism (invoking an external compiler; embedding the Eclipse compiler; etc.).

Java bytecode (`.class` binaries) can be loaded at runtime via [ClassLoader](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html)s.

In order for the loaded classes to be visible to your scripting engine, you'll need to provide them via the [ScriptEngineManager(ClassLoader)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngineManager.html#ScriptEngineManager(java.lang.ClassLoader)) constructor.

---

EDIT: based on the requirements

```
public class HelloWorld {
  public void say() {
    System.out.println("Hello, World!");
  }
}
```

This script just invokes the Java reflection API to load and instantiate a class `HelloWorld.class` from the `C:\foo\bin` directory:

```
function classImport() {
  var location = new java.net.URL('file:/C:/foo/bin/');
  var urlArray = java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(java.net.URL, 1);
  urlArray[0] = location;
  var classLoader = new java.net.URLClassLoader(urlArray);
  return classLoader.loadClass("HelloWorld");
}

var myClass = classImport();

for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
  myClass.getConstructor(null).newInstance(null).say();
}
```

There are more elegant ways of doing this, I'm sure.

Comment: Imagine that I have an application and that I don't want to change, all what I can change is the Script File that is loaded in the application.
So, if I want to do something, I can't do it in the application Java code, but just in the script File, so, I want to import a class that is external to my project, that is compiled and located in my hard drive.
Hope that I'm more explicatif :s
thnx a lot

Answer (score 1):

I would question why do this.

The solutions listed here will work. The problem is going to be that:

1. You will have a cobbled together
   solution with reflection that will
   be hard to troubleshoot.
2. Are your customers Okay with
   patching code that is loaded at
   Runtime ? Everyplace I have worked
   at is not.

Comment: The thing to do is to permit customers modifying the script files without touching the application.
I think that using introspection as it was said in the script file will work thnx a lot

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, what you are actually trying to do is load Java classes so that you can (presumably) create instances, etcetera.  The term for this is dynamic loading not importing.

Java allows you to dynamically load bytecode files (`*.class`) using the `ClassLoader.loadClass(String)` method.  There are lots of resources on this topic; e.g. the "[Class Loading](http://java.sun.com/products/jndi/tutorial/beyond/misc/classloader.html)" page from the JNDI tutorial.  Be prepared to spend some time getting your head around this topic.  In particular, since you are trying to load a class that is not on your application's normal classpath, you will need to create a new classloader to do this.  The Javadocs for the `java.lang.ClassLoader` class are [here](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html).

Java source code cannot be directly loaded, but must first be compiled using a Java compiler.  If you are using a modern JDK installation, it is possible to call the Java compiler at runtime.  But a JRE installation does not include a Java compiler.  If your platform has a Java compiler available at runtime, you can access it via the `getSystemJavaCompiler()` static method of the [`ToolProvider`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/tool/ToolProvider.html) class.  Once again, calling the Java compiler from within a running Java application is complicated.

Comment: Thnx for the answer,
What I want to do, is to add a class for example 
MyClass.java that I compiled to MyClass.class
so I would like to import MyClass that is in my hard drive, not in the packages of my project, and this, inside of a script file :
for example : 
importClass("D:\\SVN_KC\\KP\\trunk\\Protos\\ScriptEngine\\scripts\\Exemple.class");